# Autoconfigure network in Debian minimal base system

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vmware

I installed Debian base system only from network install ISO in a VMWare Workstation VM. The network adapter is set to NAT. However, I noticed that the installer didn't detect the network automatically. After some googling, I found that all I have to do is add these 3 lines to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I rebooted the system and checked eth0 with `ip a` and it wasn't there. I tried `ifup eth0` but it failed with `Failed to get interface index: No such device`.

How can I set up networking?

Comment: "checked `eth0` with `ip a` and it wasn't there" – What interfaces were there?

Comment: lo - loopback interface only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the recent changes in Debian network interfaces names which took place from Debian 9 Stretch [Read More](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames), **eth0** is no longer a valid interface name. To identify the available network interfaces on your machine, open terminal and run

```
networkctl
```

Available network interfaces will appear in the **LINK** column (IDX = the index number of the interface).
Then use the `ifup` command to activate your preferred network interface.

In my case, output from `networkctl` is

```
dev@debian:~$ networkctl
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           n/a         unmanaged 
  2 ens5             ether              n/a         unmanaged 
  3 wlo1             wlan               n/a         unmanaged 
  4 anbox0           bridge             n/a         unmanaged 
  5 docker0          bridge             n/a         unmanaged 

5 links listed.
```

To enable `wlo1` (Wireless network interface), I have to run the command:

```
ifup wlo1
```